# Rails eager loading, includes and session attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

I have a model with Missions, Users and Wits.
Wits belong to Missions and to a User.

I want to load a list of all the missions and eager load the wit for a specific user.
I need to do a LEFT OUTER JOIN and add a condition to the join.
Here is what is working for now :

```
Mission.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN wits ON wits.mission_id = missions.id AND wits.user_id = #{current_user.id}")
```

Then in my list I can do mission.wits.first to get the wit belonging to the right user.

**But it's not very rails friendly, and I have to check for the .loaded? attribute to avoid loading all the wits if the condition is not met.**

Is there a better way, hopefully using scopes, to get the job done ? Maybe adding a new virtual attribute to Mission, but I'd like to avoid making 20 calls to the database on each list.

UPDATE : In the end I'd like to see a list of mission, and for each mission the Wit status for the current_user. I'm using a gem called to acts_as_api to create a view of my list in JSON, but I cannot access a session variable inside the model, this is why I'm looking at this eager loading stuff, to load all the stuff I need from the controller.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do something like

```
Wit.includes(:mission).where(:user_id => params[:user_id])
```

Is there a reason you're querying from the Mission when it sounds like you really want just the wits? Also if you do want a list of the associated missions you could do something like this too

```
Wit.includes(:mission).where(:user_id => params[:user_id]).select(&:mission).uniq
```

Comment: No I really do want the Mission list, I just want to see for each mission if there is or not a wit associated, and if there is query it's status.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
Mission.joins(:wits).where(:wits => { :user_id => params[:user_id] }) Or
Mission.joins(:wits).where('wits.user_id' => params[:user_id] )
```

Comment: No this shows only the missions where there is a child wit.
The query I used contains AND instead of a WHERE condition.
(eg. http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/LEFT-OUTER-JOIN-with-ON-condition-or-WHERE-condition)